# Looping through 2 different Arrays to evaluate a condition in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, rules

I am trying to create a logic in database that creates rules for certain fields and then creates a condition logic based on those rules in Java.

Example1:

```
List1 = [OR, AND]
List2 = [true, false, true]
```

for example in above I want to check if (true OR false AND true) by looping through arrays in java.
I know that below code that i used is totally wrong for this requirement and is not evaluating to my required condition ie if(true OR false AND true).

Please Note, I want this code in Java only not scripting language.

```
boolean previousResult = false;
   for(int i=0;i<List1.size();i++) {
     for(int j=0; j<List2.size();j++){
        if(List1.get(i) == "OR"){
            if(true || false){
                previousResult = true;
            }
        }else{ 
            if(previousResult && true){
              previousResult = true;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

The array length will change but will follow a same pattern as below:

Example2:

```
List1 = [OR, AND, OR]
List2 = [true, false, true, false]
```

Example3:

```
List1 = [OR, AND, OR, AND]
List2 = [true, false, true, false, true]
```

Example4:

```
List1 = [OR, AND, OR, AND, OR]
List2 = [true, false, true, false, true, false]
```

Comment: You might want to find some tutorials for "Reverse Polish Notation". There are plenty, even in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop over two arrays, because you always expect you array with arguments to be one element longer than the array with operators:

```
class Playground {
    static enum BinaryOp {
        OR,
        AND
    }

    private static boolean evaluate(BinaryOp[] ops, Boolean[] vals) {
        assert vals.length > 1;
        assert ops.length == vals.length - 1;
        boolean result = vals[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < ops.length; i++) {
            if (ops[i].equals(BinaryOp.OR)) {
                result = result || vals[i + 1];
            } else {
                result = result && vals[i + 1];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        System.out.println(
            evaluate(
                new BinaryOp[] {BinaryOp.OR}, 
                new Boolean[] {false, true}));
        System.out.println(
            evaluate(
                new BinaryOp[] {BinaryOp.AND}, 
                new Boolean[] {false, true}));
        System.out.println(
            evaluate(
                new BinaryOp[] {BinaryOp.AND, BinaryOp.OR}, 
                new Boolean[] {false, true, false}));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
false
```